# See UVs for beveled curve in UV/Image Editor

Tags: bezier-curves, uv-image-editor

So I'm making character hair and I have plane beveled on to a curve like this

[image: Screenshot]

Now I'm able to see the texture I apply on it, but I want to edit the UVs for it. I usually select the faces in edit mode in order to see them in the UV editor, but I'll have to convert the curve to a mesh for that.

Is there a way to do it without converting it into a mesh? I'll be duplicating this curve a lot and editing each one.

I'm using Cycles, if that makes a difference

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
https://www.deviantart.com/vickym72/art/Blender-Empty-Decal-Tutorial-207942535

It's essentially a tutorial for manipulating decals using an empty, but you can use it for the curve as well. (Credits to: VickyM72)

Hope this helps :)

**EDIT:** Here's how to do it in cycles --> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dnmovLzKU44&ab_channel=KarstenH%C3%B6hne (Credits to: Karsten Höhne
)

**EDIT 2:** try this:

1> go to the curve tab and open Texture space

2> click Use UV for mapping

3> Click match texture space

4> Go to material node editor

5> Add your image texture

6> Add Texture coordinate node and hookup the vector of the image texture to generated

7> use the Location and Size values to manually manipulate your texture

**EDIT 3:** I made a video: https://youtu.be/bx1FdoG2xo8

Hope that works :)

Comment: I was only able to see some of those options when I switched to Blender Render. Is there a way to do this in Cycles too?

Comment: Try this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dnmovLzKU44&ab_channel=KarstenH%C3%B6hne   Let me know if this works

Comment: This is for meshes and some of the options in this video aren't available for curves. I think I'll just convert it to a mesh once I'm sure I won't be making more changes. Thanks though!

Comment: Wait I may have found a solution Look at the edit